# How to get google WEB API key to using in Expo sdk 32?

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, google-signin

I'm going to make Google login with Expo sdk 32, But In [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/), There is no how to get WEB API Key to use option 'cliendID' at LoginConfig.
How to get google WEB API key to using in Expo sdk 32?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I faced the same issue because it`s not so obvious what to use from the Expo docs, here it is

[image]

NOTICE: if you want to make it work with the standalone build, you need to set up `REVERSE_CLIENT_ID` in the app.json from GoogleService-info.plist

the instruction you can find here: `point 5` https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/#setup